# Laravel multiple nested views

Tags: php, partial-views, laravel

I'm using laravel layouts and I have a setup like this;

//Controller

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->layout->nest('submodule', 'partials.stuff');
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index');
}
```

// layout

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content');
</body>
</html>
```

// this is the content template

```
@section('content')
    <div>
        @yield('submodule')
    </div>
@endsection
```

My question is how can I insert a partial template inside the 'content' section? I also need to pass variables to this second template "submodule".

```
$this->layout->nest('partial', 'partials.partial');
```

This doesn't work because it binds the view to layout. Whereas I need to bind it to a section which is defined in the "content" template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I fixed the Laravel nested Views problem:

Using this solution you pass data to your main View as well

**Solution:**

You need to render the partials.stuff inside your home/index.blade.php view and then make a view to render 'content' of 'home/index.blade.php' in your template.php

Use `<?php render('partials.stuff') ?>`

First make your `home/index.blade.php:`

```
<div>
      <?php render('partials.stuff') ?>
</div>
```

Second render your view -- without any nested 'submodule' call

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->layout->nest('content', View::make('home.index'),$data) ;
}
```

Finally Your template will remain same -- render `{{ $content }}`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you as it has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you would typically do:

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->layout->nest('content', View::make('home.index')->nest('submodule', 'partials.stuff'));
}
```

And in your template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

and your `home/index.blade.php`:

```
<div>
     {{ $submodule }}
</div>
```