# Nesting Layouts within Layouts in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My question is about nesting layouts in Laravel. I am trying to do so as seen below, which works in most cases but produces unwanted results in others.

\\MasterLayout

```
--code for header, navbar, etc.

@yield('content)

@yield('scripts)
```

\\SubLayout

```
@extends('layouts.MasterLayout')

@section('content')
    <div>
        @yield('sidebar')

        @yield('main')
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script>scripts needed in all the relevant views</script>

    @yield('scripts.sub')
@endsection
```

\\Views

```
@extends('layouts.SubLayout')
--some code

@section('sidebar')
    --sidebar code
@endsection

@section('main')
    --main code
@endsection

@section('scripts.sub')
    <script>scripts only needed in this view</script>
@endsection
```

In my own case, I have a further layer of nesting (a subsublayout). My controller simply redirects to the view without doing anything special. E.g.,

```
public function start()
{
    return view('createproject/start');
}
```

This works pretty well in many cases, but there are some problems. For example, I can't simply include php files in the SubLayout that are needed in the views. Those includes have to go in the file in which they are being used in order to gain access to their functions. Also, placing `<div></div>` tags directly outside an @yield sometimes has a different effect than placing them directly inside the @section to which the @yield points. Also, while the pages work, I have gotten some strange warning messages such as that I have declared DOCTYPE multiple times or not at all, when neither is true as far as I can tell. So while the method of nesting seems to work, it's a bit unwieldy and I'm not convinced it represents best practice.

Hence, my question for the community is this: Is my suggested method of nesting layouts generally appropriate (perhaps with some caveats that address the problems I'm having) or does it exhibit some fundamental problem/confusion?

There is a related Stack Q&A that I've found here: [Laravel multiple nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125229/laravel-multiple-nested-views) but the nest() function referenced there is no longer discussed in more recent versions of the Laravel documentation (have I missed it?), so I wonder if it's still needed.

Comment: As a note regarding your last paragraph: just because something is not present in all versions of the documentation it doesn't mean it's been removed (the Laravel Docs can be lacking in some respects). However that `nest` view method is still present as denoted by the Laravel [`Illuminate\View\View`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_nest) class API. So when in doubt, the API docs are always a good place to look.

Comment: Thanks, this his helpful. So I wonder if making using of several layers of nesting via that function is the best practice here or is my suggested method of having layouts extend other layouts just fine.

Comment: If you  need a more than 1 level of nest I wold jut use @include for the 2 level on. You now you can also pass variables to the included view? How about include views sidebar instead extending and so getting rid of the extends that is messing with you

Answer (score 0):

you can use components and slots for that
[components-and-slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots)